# PhonecallReceiver not working on android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm having an app the all it does it shows a toast every time a phonecall for the device has been made.

But my Reciever isn't called when a call has been made, and i dont see anything, 
why is that ?

my BroadcastReciever:

```
public class PhoneStateReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            Toast.makeText(context," Receiver start ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thetaskmasterapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReciver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two permissions you had used are dangerous permissions (READ_PHONE_STATE & PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS). So please request permission to access these from user as run-time permissions for devices having os greater than or equal to 23(Marshmallow). You can refer for requesting run-time permissions to user

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview